# How can we find highest and lowest address of heap

Tags: c

Can anyone suggest, how can we find highest and lowest address of heap using C?

Comment: That can only be done for (some) specific C implementation. Not in any portable/standard way. But it also looks completely irrelevant, are you looking for `available_memory()` or something?

Comment: If this is just for academic interest than I *suppose* you could iteratively malloc and free until you find the largest single block that can be allocated before malloc starts to fail. Your heap start would then be (approximately) the start address of this block and the heap end would be (approximately) the start address + the size of the block. This will fail for some architectures though, e.g. 32 bit Mac OS X where you have an island in the middle of the heap (where dylibs live).

Comment: Consider your computer draws memory from other computers in the network :-) What address is lower `\\MARKETING\memory\0xbaddecaf` or `\\WAREHOUSE\memory\0xdeadbeef`?

Comment: @pmg: Presumably all this would be mapped into a flat virtual-address space by the MMU, though?

Comment: @Oli: that is meant to be the output of `printf("%p", (void*)&object);`. Of course I'm only *half* kidding!

Comment: @XYZ Maybe you'd like to tell us the real problem? What exactly are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: For my OS where everyting fits in 32kB RAM i can chek in linker :D

Answer (score 6):

On a Linux system, you can use sbrk() with a 0 argument to find one end. You might be able to find the other end by understanding your program loader's segment ordering and examining etext and edata - see the end(3) manpage.

All of this is non-standard and outside the scope of C itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your calls to `malloc` to keep track of the lowest and highest address seen so far at each call:

```
extern unsigned char *lowest, *highest;
unsigned char *tmp = malloc(size);
if (!tmp) return 0;
if (!lowest || tmp < lowest) lowest = tmp;
if (tmp+size > highest) highest = tmp;
return tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't in C.  If you check the language standard, you'll notice that the concept is never mentioned.

The heap is an implementation detail used in some operating environments (OK almost all of them).